# Page refreshes/ scrolls top when AJAX GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, page-refresh

I have a problem with my page. When i click a div my code makes:
1. `.empty()` div .channelBoxes
2. AJAX call then appending new divs .Box.
After click the page reloads/scrolls to top. I want to prevent this action but don't know what causes the problem. I tried `.preventDefault()`, `return false;`, deleting `<a>` tags and nothing seems fix this problem. Please help me.
Any suggestion to improve code are welcome.
Here is a link to my code:

http://codepen.io/Felnyr/pen/RKGqBE

Comment: Hmmm... works fine for me with `.preventDefault()`? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrjVQp

Comment: try click on the game name divs (navigation) the problem is here

Comment: Yep - that's what I did and fixed... It's still not working for you with the code pen I gave you?

Comment: Ok this is wierd maybe codepen bug or something but i tried this solution before and did't worked now it works fine O.o Appreciate for commitment.

Comment: Hey - as long as it works eventually! ; )